# cx_Freeze throws an error when building if packages are involved

Tags: zeromq, cx-freeze

cx_Freeze successfully converts a `.py` file to an `.exe` if no other packages are involved.

But when `pandas` is included, the setup fails with this message:

```
File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\hooks.py", line 1324, in load_zmq
    libzmq = __import__("zmq", fromlist=["libzmq"]).libzmq
AttributeError: module 'zmq' has no attribute 'libzmq'
```

This is the contents of the `setup.py`:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

build_exe_options = {"packages": ["pandas"]}

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(  name = "test",
        version = "0.1",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("test.py", base=base)])
```

So far I've tried creating a different environment in anaconda to run cx_freeze to see if the problem resolves itself that way.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Well, commenting out the .libzmq attribute in hooks.py worked...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've spent a long time trying to find an answer to this question, but luckily it can be found [here](https://github.com/marcelotduarte/cx_Freeze/issues/919). It seems it was a bug inherent to cx_freeze.

Although the link provided to download the wheels no longer works, the patch has been added to the latest development version (6.6.0 if I recall correctly). You can install it directly from github, as such:

```
python -m pip install git+https://github.com/marcelotduarte/cx_Freeze.git
```

Doing this fixed the error for me (and enabled me to discover other errors that I had to deal with!).